# XCode 4 stopped highlight and recognizing UIKit classes on project

Tags: xcode, xcode4, uikit, codehighlighter

Hi i get problem with xCode 4.

I develope project with XCode4 on home and on work.

And i store it on my USB flash drive.

Today i get some problem.

I open xib file for add outlet to code and get next error "Could not insert new outlet connection: Could not find any information for the class named ..."
Class exist and property of xib file setted correctly.
[Could not insert new outlet connection: Could not find any information for the class named](http://www.cyberforum.ru/attachment.php?attachmentid=99009&d=1317882267)

Ok, think i, i write code and the connect using Files owner.

Next step i open code editor of .h class file and try to write UI... and see nothing. i dont get list of classes UI types

Next i saw what XCode code editor does not highlighting classes of UIKit and else frameworks too.

But i dont have this error on another projects and on it project but on home computer.

Some body have same problem?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this: Close your project. Choose Window > Organizer from the main menu. Select the Projects panel. Select and delete all copies of your project from the list. Open the project again (Xcode will rebuild the necessary information).

This will *not* delete your project, but the index and other information Xcode discovers about your project. As I said, Xcode will rebuild the information as soon as you re-open the project.

Comment: Indeed, this is the solution - just closing the project and reopening doesn't fix it (though it does fix many other Xcode problems).  What seems to have caused it for me was having refactored a UIViewController to have a different name.

Answer (score 2):

We had a really similar problem happen to us and none of the help out there worked. What did end up fixing it was deleting the .m and .h file from xcode (resource only) and then dragging them back into the project from the project folder. It seemed to relink everything and make it work again.

Answer (score 1):

Just add .m files in Compile Sources under:

```
<My Project> 
   -- TARGETS <My App Name>
        -- Build Phase tab 
          -- Compile Sources
```

It fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that .m file was moved inside en.lproj folder.

Just delete (reference only) the .m file from the Xcode and moved .m out of the en.lproj.
Add it again.Don't worry, you will get all your connections back.

It will fix the issue.